# Build.gradle is syntax error? How I can fix this?

Tags: flutter, gradle, firebase-authentication

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I write flutter with firebase and I use Authentication and I meet this syntax error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUlI5.png)

How to fix this somepeople can help me

Answer (score 0):

> You Simply Need to Download Google-Services file
> App>Build.gradle

```
  plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
    
        // Add the Google services Gradle plugin
        id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Bro I got this can You help me